# Time complexity on Hash Map Resizing

Tags: hashmap, resize, time-complexity

How do you ensure O(1) complexity of insertion/deletion at the instant of hash map re-sizing?

Answer (score 1):

That O(1) time in a hash map is the amortized time. During a resize various strategies might be adopted, like doubling the size of the underlying array or increasing its size by a fixed amount. To answer your question, O(1) absolute time complexity is not maintained at the instant of hash map resizing.